# JQuery/javascript drop a div anywhere of the parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, 2d, coordinates

I am developing a program with jQuery/javascript to design a switch board. User can add switches(different sizes and margins each) to the board and order the switches according to user's choice. I need make this switches can add anywhere inside parent div and drag and drop them anywhere without automatically aligning and determine the coordinates of the child div relative to parent div.Please can anyone have an idea to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look Jquery ui documentation. [Here](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Comment: Thank you, That is what I looking for!